# Can MapboxGL use nearest neighbour interpolation for overlay image?

Tags: leaflet, interpolation, mapbox, overlay, mapbox-gl

In HTML+CSS version of mapbox/leaflet I can set `image-rendering` option for `.leaflet-image-layer` with CSS to choose interpolation method. How can I make this in GL renderer?

---

**Update: Solved**

You can set nearest neighbour interpolation for all raster textures added to layers.

You need to change LINEAR parameter to NEAREST in 137 line of [ImageSource](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/master/js/source/image_source.js)

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For a coding question like this we need you to use the [edit] button beneath it to inclu8de a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: No it can't, but simple patch is possible. Added to post.